# How come k is zero?

Tags: c, output

In the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i=-3,j=2,k=0,m;
    m=++i||++j&&++k;
    printf("%d %d %d %d",i,j,k,m);
}
```

> Output:
>   -2 2 0 1

Why is k = 0? because I think *k* also gets executed because of **&&** operator?

Comment: Why are you writing code that is difficult to read?

Answer (score 8):

C uses short circuit-logic - since `++i` isn't zero, it's true, and since it's the left-hand side of an `||` operator, we know no matter what's on the right-hand side, it will result to true. Hence, C (and a bunch of similar languages) don't even bother evaluating the right hand side, and just quickly return true. Since `++k` is never evaluated, `k` remains unchanged, and is still `0` after the `m=++i||++j&&++k;` statement.

Comment: he might need to know that [`&&` has higher precedence than `||`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) therefore the expression is parsed as `(++i) || (++j && ++k)`